# Function of function in python. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, colossus

I am new to python and I need to work with it for my master thesis.

The first function called p_nfw_mean2 works and it uses colossus, a python toolkit for calculations pertaining to cosmology . I don't understand why when I call the function clumping_factor that uses the first one p_nfw_mean2 I get:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The problem is p_nfw_mean2 in clumping_factor, because if I remove it the code works perfectly.

Here are the functions:

```
#Mean of NFW profile square
def p_nfw_mean2(z, Mvir):
    Rvir = peaks.lagrangianR(Mvir)
    cvir, mask = concentration.modelDiemer19(Mvir, z)
    p_nfw = profile_nfw.NFWProfile(Mvir, cvir, z, mdef = 'vir')
    func = lambda r: p_nfw.density(r)**2 * r**2
    result, none = integrate.quadrature(func, 0.0, Rvir, tol=1e-7, rtol=1e-7, maxiter=1000)
    return 4.0 * pi * result

#Clumping factor
def clumping_factor(z):
    func = lambda Mvir, z: (ro_m / Mvir) * mass_function.massFunction(Mvir, z, q_in='M', q_out='M2dndM', mdef='fof', model='sheth99') * p_nfw_mean2(z, Mvir)
    result, none = integrate.quadrature(func, Mvir_min, Mvir_max, args=(z,), tol=1e-7, rtol=1e-7, maxiter=1000)
    return result
```

I get:

```
 File "mynotebook.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(mm.clumping_factor(z))
  File "/Users/Noemi/Desktop/mymodule.py", line 86, in clumping_factor
    result, none = integrate.quadrature(func, Mvir_min, Mvir_max, args=(z,), tol=1e-7, rtol=1e-7, maxiter=1000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 242, in quadrature
    newval = fixed_quad(vfunc, a, b, (), n)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 123, in fixed_quad
    return (b-a)/2.0 * np.sum(w*func(y, *args), axis=-1), None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 153, in vfunc
    return func(x, *args)
  File "/Users/Noemi/Desktop/mymodule.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    func = lambda Mvir, z: (ro_m / Mvir) * mass_function.massFunction(Mvir, z, q_in='M', q_out='M2dndM', mdef='fof', model='sheth99') * p_nfw_mean2(z, Mvir)
  File "/Users/Noemi/Desktop/mymodule.py", line 80, in p_nfw_mean2
    result, none = integrate.quadrature(func, 0.0, Rvir, tol=1e-7, rtol=1e-7, maxiter=1000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 242, in quadrature
    newval = fixed_quad(vfunc, a, b, (), n)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 119, in fixed_quad
    if np.isinf(a) or np.isinf(b):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Maybe it has something to do with numpy.integrate

Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: I added it! @DYZ

Comment: Should `Rvir` be an array in the call to `integrate.quadrature` in `p_nfw_mean2`?

Comment: @SebastianDziadzio It could be but I use only floats, I give Mvir as a float so I think Rvir should also be a float. Sorry but I am new to python and coding in general

Comment: I think the problem might be that it should be a float but it is in fact an array. You can try printing `type(Rvir)` to verify that.

Comment: @SebastianDziadzio You are right! It gives <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, how can I change it?

Comment: If the array only has a single value, you can do `Rvir = Rvir.item` to extract it. Should `peaks.lagrangianR` return a single number?

Comment: @SebastianDziadzio Here is the explanation of  `peaks.lagrangianR`: [https://bdiemer.bitbucket.io/colossus/lss_peaks.html#lss.peaks.lagrangianR]. I thought that if `Mvir` is a float also `Rvir` should be

Comment: You can see in the documentation that it returns an `array_like`. It seems that if you give it a number it will still return an array, but with one element. You can use `Rvir.item` to extract that element.